# writing to .csv with INTO OUTFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I'm trying to write the results of a select statement to a .csv file using `INTO OUTFILE`.

I've been fiddling with it now for a few hours and I've read through many other related questions on here.

For some reason when I run my query absolutely nothing happens. The page doesn't show any errors or anything and the file is not being created.

Has anyone else ever had this problem and could someone tell me if there is a problem with my SQL?

```
$customers=dbqueryintoarray('
SELECT customer_contacts.Title, customer_contacts.FirstName, 
       customer_contacts.Surname, customer_contacts.Email, 
       customers.LanguageID, customers.DeliveryCountryID 
INTO OUTFILE \'z:/jobs.csv\' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
FROM jobs 
JOIN customer_contacts ON jobs.ContactID = customer_contacts.ContactID 
JOIN customers ON jobs.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID 
JOIN equipment ON jobs.EquipmentID = equipment.EquipmentID 
JOIN branches ON jobs.BranchID = branches.BranchID 
WHERE BranchName = "'.$location.'" AND ModelNumber LIKE "%6ES5%"
');
```

I've checked and I do have permissions. I have used

> or die(mysql_error())

but this doesn't produce any errors, it just removes everything from the page from that point downwards. I'm really stuck

Comment: Does MySQL have access to Z:\ ?

Comment: Noticed the path to the file is incorrect. In windows, it shoudl be z:\jobs.csv.  Make sure to escape the backslash (z:\\jobs.csv).

Comment: well im not sure but Ive tried a range of directories like c:, z:, s: ad i get nothing for all of these

Answer (score 0):

How about "C:\\jobs.csv"? I have no experience with this on windows but I think it doesn't replace \ by / as php does.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the quotes on the file path:

```
... INTO OUTFILE 'z:\jobs.csv'
```

Escaping them prevents MySQL from seeing that filename as a string. It'll be seen as a syntax error, e.g:

```
mysql> select '1' into outfile \'/tmp/z.txt\';
ERROR:
Unknown command '\''.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\''.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'/tmp/z.txt\'' at line 1
```

Just because you're not seeing any errors means nothing. You have to ASK for errors in mysql, e.g:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ok I stopped escaping the quotes on the file path but (or die(mysql_error());) doesnt produce any errors still

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, enclose main query with double quota:

```
$customers=dbqueryintoarray("
SELECT customer_contacts.Title, customer_contacts.FirstName, customer_contacts.Surname, 
customer_contacts.Email, customers.LanguageID, customers.DeliveryCountryID 
INTO OUTFILE 'z:\\jobs.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM jobs 
JOIN customer_contacts ON jobs.ContactID = customer_contacts.ContactID 
JOIN customers ON jobs.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID 
JOIN equipment ON jobs.EquipmentID = equipment.EquipmentID 
JOIN branches ON jobs.BranchID = branches.BranchID 
WHERE BranchName = '$location' AND ModelNumber LIKE '%6ES5%'
");
```

Comment: i've ammended my code to follow your instructions but still I get nothing. do i need this? (OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"') because i think its causing me problems. that " appears to be cutting my sql statement short even though I have escaped it